# convert a timestamp in a dictionary to a date in Python

Tags: python, pandas, date, dictionary

i would like to convert in the dictionary the date to a date format, instead of timestamp

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=5, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val' : np.random.randn(len(rng))}) 
df_dict=dict(df.values)
df_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the `dataframe`?

This will create a dictionary with the dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=5, freq='D')
val = np.random.randn(len(rng))

a_dict = {k.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'): val[i] for i, k in enumerate(rng)}

print(a_dict)

""" Example Output
{'2015-02-24': -0.07282471983155527, 
 '2015-02-25': -0.41013201628459295, 
 '2015-02-26': -0.30191959095195636, 
 '2015-02-27': 2.294166235809919, 
 '2015-02-28': 1.465762794927064}
"""
```

If you do need the `dataframe` this will convert the 'timestamp' column to a date.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=5, freq='D')

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val' : np.random.randn(len(rng))}) 

df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.date

df_dict=dict(df.values)

print(df_dict)


""" Example Output
{datetime.date(2015, 2, 24): 0.9373082567531855, 
 datetime.date(2015, 2, 25): -1.0216555373785885, 
 datetime.date(2015, 2, 26): -0.678286157996744, 
 datetime.date(2015, 2, 27): 1.6241576949559353, 
 datetime.date(2015, 2, 28): 0.9808792692339873}
"""
```

If you want a formatted date you could use this.

```py
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


""" Example Output
{'2015-02-24': -0.7589858965910741, 
 '2015-02-25': -0.2388121120855477, 
 '2015-02-26': 0.8886907324406109, 
 '2015-02-27': -0.7603131636217634, 
 '2015-02-28': 0.675297144576459}
"""
```

Comment: my starting point is a dataframe, so I have to convert it to a dictionary with the proper format, but in the conversion that you see df_dict=dict(df.values) it creates a timestamp format

Comment: I've added code to convert the `Date` column of the dataframe.